# Get The window that runs python

Tags: python, windows, terminal

I want to run some code only when I focus on the window that runs Python
e.g. VSCode, PowerShell, etc.

I tried this

```
desired = [
    "PowerShell",
    "Visual Studio Code",

]

def do(key):
    try: active = gw.getActiveWindow().title
    except: active = ""
    for i in desired:
        if i.lower() in str(active).lower():
            # do something
```

But if I don't use PowerShell or VSCode it won't work
I want it works on ANY terminals too

and if I run python in PowerShell, I can still control it on VSCode
which is not what I want to see

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have experience of using of win32gui ( google library):

```
import win32gui

def is_window_in_focus(window_title):
    active_window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    active_window_title = win32gui.GetWindowText(active_window)
    return window_title.lower() in active_window_title.lower()

def do():
    if is_window_in_focus("PowerShell") or is_window_in_focus("Visual Studio Code"):
        # Your code here

# Test if the window is in focus when calling the do() function
do()
```

Comment: if I run python in PowerShell, I can still control it on VSCode